# Alchemy Websocket multi-threaded messages

Tags: multithreading, websocket, alchemy-websockets

I am using Alchemy-Websockets for a server where I send and receive messages from clients outside, in its own thread on the server.  This works great, but now I want to also send messages that originate on the server in a different thread.  Here is my main setup:

```
    public WebSocket(int port, IRedisClient _redis)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server at " + port);
        Redis = _redis;
        // instantiate a new server - acceptable port and IP range,
        // and set up your methods.
        //clients = new Dictionary<string, UserContext>();
        subscriber_list = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, UserContext>>{ };

        var aServer = new WebSocketServer(port, System.Net.IPAddress.Any)
        {
            OnReceive = OnReceive,
            OnConnect = OnConnect,
            OnConnected = OnConnected,
            OnDisconnect = OnDisconnect,
            TimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
        };
        aServer.Start();
    }
```

This code is in a class that is started on its own thread.  The question is if I want to send data to clients of this websocket, how do I handle the multi-threading?  Do I just add a locking mechanism so that a particular "UserContext" is not being used at the same time as my use of it?  Do I put a while loop after the aServer.Start() line and block on my server based communications that I'm waiting for?  Like this?:

```
    aServer.Start();
    while(true){
      // block on messages from my other thread (not from the websocket)
      // get lock for a user context
      UserContext.Send(myMessage);
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

The Thread.Sleep is not meant to cause the websocket to sleep and miss messages over the socket.  Looking at other examples I think this should not happen as the alchemy server is in its own thread as well.

Answer (score 1):

Alchemy is asynchronous internally, but if you block a handler with a `while(true) + Thread.Sleep` , you will probably block the connection and also block an execution thread peer connection.

You should register the `UserContext` somewhere, like a list of current connections associated by clientID or userID, or userId+connectionID. And every time you want to send something to users, you go through that list, find the connection and send stuff. You will have to be carefull and ensure you do not write from two threads in the same `UserContext`, so consider using the Producer/Consumer pattern.

There are many many ways of doing this. But you cannot just block an event handler with a endless loop.

Comment: I agree that I can't block an event handler, but I don't think this is an event handler.  "OnReceive" and the other callbacks are the event handlers, are they not?  What I'm doing here is to put a while loop outside of any event handler, and then get the lock on the UserContext, and send my message.  Perhaps that was not clear in the code?